# Parse google web search to xml/json

Tags: java, android, xml, json, parsing

I need to receive an editable format (xml or json or otherwise) the result of a google search (similar to the result returned in the search at google.com).

Someone health as I do?
thank you

Comment: I tried to find a way to convert these results to json for example, but find no way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google no longer provides a service to get results in a programmatic manner from their regular search engine. You can use the Google custom search API, although that is not the same as their general search engine, as that is designed only to index your site.

While it's possible to parse an HTML result from the google search engine, it's against their terms of service and could potentially lead to your IP address being banned from searching.

Comment: So there is no way to list the results in my application? In order to not go against the terms of use?

Comment: Exactly. If google gave their results out there wouldn't be a reason for people to view Google.com because people could just produce ad free versions of it, and then they'd never make money.

Comment: And you know that you can include an application android web search?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that question.